How to Fix "Configuration with name 'implementation' not found." Error in gradle kotlin
Every time I try to build the Gradle file it gives me the error "Configuration with name 'implementation' not found." I have no idea what the problem is. the code is in Kotlin for Gradle, any idea on why it is crashing?
val lwjglVersion = "3.3.4"
val `lwjgl3-awtVersion` = "0.1.8"
val lwjglNatives = "natives-windows"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    "implementation"(platform("org.lwjgl:lwjgl-bom:$lwjglVersion"))

    "implementation"("org.lwjgl", "lwjgl")
    "implementation"("org.lwjgl", "lwjgl-assimp")
    "implementation"("org.lwjgl", "lwjgl-bgfx")
    "implementation"("org.lwjgl", "lwjgl-glfw")
    "implementation"("org.lwjgl", "lwjgl-nanovg")
    "implementation"("org.lwjgl", "lwjgl-nuklear")
    "implementation"("org.lwjgl", "lwjgl-openal")
    "implementation"("org.lwjgl", "lwjgl-opengl")
    "implementation"("org.lwjgl", "lwjgl-par")
    "implementation"("org.lwjgl", "lwjgl-stb")
    "implementation"("org.lwjgl", "lwjgl-vulkan")
    "runtimeOnly"("org.lwjgl", "lwjgl", classifier = lwjglNatives)
    "runtimeOnly"("org.lwjgl", "lwjgl-assimp", classifier = lwjglNatives)
    "runtimeOnly"("org.lwjgl", "lwjgl-bgfx", classifier = lwjglNatives)
    "runtimeOnly"("org.lwjgl", "lwjgl-glfw", classifier = lwjglNatives)
    "runtimeOnly"("org.lwjgl", "lwjgl-nanovg", classifier = lwjglNatives)
    "runtimeOnly"("org.lwjgl", "lwjgl-nuklear", classifier = lwjglNatives)
    "runtimeOnly"("org.lwjgl", "lwjgl-openal", classifier = lwjglNatives)
    "runtimeOnly"("org.lwjgl", "lwjgl-opengl", classifier = lwjglNatives)
    "runtimeOnly"("org.lwjgl", "lwjgl-par", classifier = lwjglNatives)
    "runtimeOnly"("org.lwjgl", "lwjgl-stb", classifier = lwjglNatives)
    "implementation"("org.lwjglx", "lwjgl3-awt", `lwjgl3-awtVersion`)
}

any help will be appreciated

Your IDE should be complaining about almost every line of that. Don't use quotes around implementation.

it complains if i don't
